# Do I always have to wait before clicking?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm writing some tests for my site using [WebdriverIO](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio) alongside Mocha/Chai, but when I do this:

```
it('select application', function(done) {
    client
        .click('.disciplinetext > table:nth-child(7) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)')
        // more stuff
```

The element doesn't exist yet (wasn't rendered). Shouldn't `.click()` implicitly wait for the page to finish loading before it actually attempts to click the element?

It works fine if I slap this line before it:

```
.waitFor('.disciplinetext > table:nth-child(7) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)',1000)
```

But I don't want to have to throw a `waitFor` before every `.setValue()`, `.click()`, `.getText()`, or any other [API command](http://webdriver.io/api.html). Am I missing something?

Is there either a command to wait for the whole page to load, or a setting to make implicitly wait before accessing an element?

Comment: `.click` "will" implicitly wait for the page to load before ever operating on an element. Is this element being appended to the DOM via ajax?

Comment: @sircapsalot: No, it's in the Ctrl+U page source on page load.

Comment: May be the second comment in this discussion (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/8n55XfpDSGo) would be helpful. FYI, there is an `implicitWait` implementation in the Java, Python, Ruby bindings for the selenium webdriver.

Comment: the nature of the problem doesn't sound to be stemming from the implicitWait.. there is no reason it shouldn't be clicking. the only thing i can picture is that it is appended by ajax. and ajax doesn't play nicely with any automation framework out there.

Comment: @Amey: I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs/). I want to use PhantomJS as my browser. My understanding with WebdriverJS is that if you chain all the methods together it will wait for the previous one to finish before running the next.

Comment: @sircapsalot: I had this problem when I used the Python driver in the past too... it's definitely not AJAX; I can see the element in the HTML when I view the source code.

Comment: @Mark, `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` works for Python.

Comment: @Amey doesn't really help him as he's using webdriverjs :)

Comment: @sircapsalot, thats true. But was just stating that the python one works. :)

Comment: @mpen for starters, *implicit waits* aren't a best practice, moreover, they are frowned upon in the web-automation scene. There is no excuse for not using *explicit waits*. I know your question entailed an implicit wait approach, but trust me, after hundreds of hours of doing this stuff, if you want to sleep well at night while your regression is running, you will want to do some explicit waiting for each of your commands. I'll add an answer tomorrow (need some ZZzzZZ's now).
Also, can we do something about that accepted answer? **:)** There's like 0 relevance to it.

Comment: @iamdanchiv You might be right, my point was only that I'm pretty sure I used the correct word in my question :-) I'm still figuring out this Selenium test stuff, I haven't had a lot of luck yet getting the tests to run consistently. I don't know why I checked that answer, I probably gave up waiting for a proper one. Will look forward to your answer tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 9):

The `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(ms)` function does exist in the [WebdriverJS Reference API Docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait). This API is for the official Javascript API that Selenium supports and @sircapsalot's excerpt comes from. However, it is much cleaner than looking at the Google Code and much easier to navigate.

Comment: This actually not an answer regarding webdriver-io.

Comment: that link is broken, I think it's here now: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait

Answer (score 2):

You can set the duration of the implicit wait via:

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

The default setting is 0, which is why click() fires instantly.

Obviously this is a c# example, but hopefully you can translate it.

I think this is a a webdriverjs example:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: `webdriverjs.manage` doesn't exist unfortunately. Can't find any reference to `implicitlyWait` in the source either :-(

Comment: When I looked here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits - I found the information on implictlywaits default being 0 here.  Not sure why the documentation doesn't line up with the code.

Comment: This actually not an answer regarding webdriver-io.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like webdriverjs even has an implicit timeout, ergo, no way to change it.

1 solution I can think of, is to override the `click()` method to something like this... (note that this is psuedo.)

```
click = function(what) {
  waitFor(what);
  super(what);
}
```

it's an explicit wait, but we can consider it implicit `;)`

**EDIT:**
I took a further look into the "inner sanctum" of webdriverjs, and i found this excerpt from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#1130)

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param {number} ms The amount of time to wait, in milliseconds.
 * @return {!webdriver.promise.Promise} A promise that will be resolved when the
 *     implicit wait timeout has been set.
 */
webdriver.WebDriver.Timeouts.prototype.implicitlyWait = function(ms) {
  return this.driver_.schedule(
      new webdriver.Command(webdriver.CommandName.IMPLICITLY_WAIT).
          setParameter('ms', ms < 0 ? 0 : ms),
      'WebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(' + ms + ')');
};
```

Try doing some javascript magic to override this method.

Comment: I think that's a different library than the one I'm using... although it's not too late to switch if that one works better.

Comment: you're absolutely right... this is actually seleniums official JavaScript API.  my first method would work if you can figure it out :)

Comment: Yeah, I came up with this before you posted that: `client.addCommand('waitClick', function(selector, ms) {
    return this.waitFor(selector, ms || 1000, function(err) {
        expect(err, selector).to.be.null;
    }).click(selector);
});` (which hooks in a mocha/chai test too)... it's not bad, but the library seems to have a few other problems too. Trying the official one now....documentation is atrocious.

Comment: Google Code... is atrocious

Comment: @Mark which other problems do you have with WebdriverJS? And yes, your approach with `addCommand` would be the way to go. You could also pass an callback to the custom function and it would behave like `click`.

Comment: @ChristianB: I don't remember now; haven't touched this for awhile. I think there's some problems with the selenium webdriver itself; it doesn't behave the same in every browser. IE types really slowly, safari or one of the other browsers is too fast (doesn't wait for anything). Some of them produce inconsistent screenshots (the gradients on a `<select>` are changing by a few pixels?? could be the browser's fault) or are maybe a pixel taller in some cases... injecting and working with jQuery/Sizzle isn't pleasant. None of it has been a good experience, really.